# SSRS when to use shared data source vs tie to single report

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS is it best practice used shared data source or tie it to report?  I like tie it to report so you can basically move the report to any folder but I have heard people say it's better to use a shared data source and create that data source so any report that connects to it should use it.

When is it better to use shared vs tie it in the report itself?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared data source is generally best practice, and while I'm sure there are probably a small number of situations that exist where an embedded data source would be technically better than shared (or at least not worse), I can't think of any off the top of my head other than possibly things like one-time testing or something like that. If you only use embedded data sources and if you *ever* have to change something about that data source in the future, you will have to touch every single report that uses said data source.